# Access Typescript function from Javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm curious about how to call a function (in my Typescript file) from my Javascript file.

I know its possible to call between two javascript files.

This is from my function in my javascript file `getRowData()` is a function in my typescript file.

```
$table.on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
    $('.success').removeClass('success');
    $($element).addClass('success');
    getRowData();
}
```

And this is my Typescript file

```
export class CustomersScreen extends Screen<void> {
    private customer: CustomerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
    private selectedCustomerID: string = "";
    private listOfCustomers: CustomerViewModel[];
    private theTemplate: string = "profile";

    constructor() {
        super("customers", ActiveMenuItem.Customers, FooterActionsSet.None);
    }

    private clearSelection = () => {
        this.customer = new CustomerViewModel();
        this.selectedCustomerID = null;
    };

    public getRowData() {
        alert("something");
    }; 
}
```

Chrome console just keeps telling me `getRowData` is not defined.

Comment: The `getRowData` method is declared on instances of `CustomerScreen`. It's not going to show up on the `window` object...

Comment: Ok, any tips on what to do about it? Since I want to use the variables inside the CustomerScreen class in my getRowData function

Comment: `new CustomersScreen().getRowData()` will work from any JS file that has access to `CustomersScreen`. What compiler setting do you have for `module`? Are you using any JS module loader already? Are you using a bundler like Browserify or Webpack?

Comment: Do they need to be in a class? Can't you just declare them as regular variables and functions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do 2 things :

- export the function in your JS file (in order to make it available from out)
- import your JS file into your Typescript

For example in Angular2 using TypeScript, if I need to use Observable in my Component, I have to :

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'; in my TS File
```

In rxjs/RX there is an export :

```
exports.Observable = Observable_1.Observable;
```